# channels.fetch() throwing DiscordAPIError: Missing Access

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm trying to wrap my heading around discord.js API. It's my first API/project.
I'm trying to log a channels name. The discord documentation offers this example code

```
// Fetch a channel by its id
client.channels.fetch('actualIdHere')
  .then(channel => console.log(channel.name))
  .catch(console.error);
```

This throws a missing access error. I have permissions enabled. Here's my setup.

```
// Require the necessary discord.js classes
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');
const { token } = require('./config.json');

// declare intents
const myIntents = new Intents();
myIntents.add(
    [
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INTEGRATIONS,
        Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    ],
);

// Create a new client instance
const client = new Client({ intents: myIntents });

client.login(token);
```

[Here are my permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZSo8B.png)

Here's the logout (note, where are these promises coming from?)

```
AsyncQueue { promises: [] }
AsyncQueue { promises: [] }
DiscordAPIError: Missing Access
    at RequestHandler.execute (C:\Users\name\discord-greed-game-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:351:13)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
    at async RequestHandler.push (C:\Users\name\discord-greed-game-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\rest\RequestHandler.js:52:14)
    at async ChannelManager.fetch (C:\Users\name\discord-greed-game-bot\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\ChannelManager.js:115:18) {
  method: 'get',
  path: '/channels/actualIdHere',
  code: 50001,
  httpStatus: 403,
  requestData: { json: undefined, files: [] }
}
```

Comment: Does the bot have the permissions in the server?

Comment: is that distinct from the permissions I shared in the post?

Comment: Can u await it, and log again

Comment: @Azer154 can you provide the specific syntax? I tried a few things and didn't get any result.

Comment: The error clearly states that the bot can't access the channel. Try going into that channel with your account, and check if you see the bot online in the member list. If you can't see it, then edit the channel permissions and add the "VIEW_CHANNEL" permission to the bot. Your code is correct, it is - most likely - a permission issue.

Comment: @Fowled I included a screenshot of my permissions in OP (they include the read messages/view channel permission). Here's an image of the bot in the channel https://ibb.co/dB6rwPn

Comment: I also updated my permissions in the actual discord channel. I missed that before but I'm getting another error 
``` TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'name')```

Comment: @Wheelwright this is super weird, I don't really know what's going on. From what I've seen on the internet, the error code "50001" may be related to the OAuth2 scopes not registering correctly - you could try reinviting the bot and make sure the `application.commands` scope is checked. If that doesn't work, then try to invite the bot with **Administrator** privileges to check if the "missing permissions" error message persists - even though it shouldn't. Don't hesitate to tag me if you have any question/issue or even progress you'd like to share!

Comment: I've just seen your second message; the error simply states that the channel couldn't be fetched, therefore, your program can't read its `.name` property. That behaviour isn't really expected. Could you try reinstalling `discord.js@latest` and see if there's any progress?

Comment: @Fowled ahh, thanks for the suggestions. I'll give it a try. I recently did a big reinstall of node and vscode in which I (probably ill-advisedly) deleted every node_modules or vscode files I could find on my machine. I've since reinstalled both and everything seems to run fine. But could I have messed sth up there?

Comment: @Wheelwright everyone makes mistakes! Don't forget `discord.js` v13 requires Node.js version **16.6.0** or newer. Try doing a clean install of your modules on that Node.js version - delete the `node_modules` and `package-lock.json` project files and enter `npm install`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241470/discussion-between-fowled-and-wheelwright).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After chatting a bit with OP, it seems that the problem came from these lines of code being executed before the `<Discord>.Client` was ready to run commands. That's the reason why any code that has to be executed by the bot should be placed inside an event, and after the `ready` one has been emitted. As suggested by @Wheelwright, a workaround could be to `setTimeout()` that code, in order to let the bot have some time to connect, but it isn't recommended, due to API latency which, sometimes, requires more time to login.

```js
client.once('ready', bot => {
    console.log(`Ready! Logged in as ${bot.user.tag}.`);

   client.channels.fetch('idOfTheChannel')
     .then(channel => console.log(channel.name))
     .catch(console.error);
});
```